# Issues putting multiple panels into a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

This is sort of two questions on the same issue. I am working on a digital clock project that will look like this when finished:

[image: digital clock]

There are 9 panels in the one frame.  One panel of the `TitlePanel` class, 6 of the `DigitPanel` class, and 2 of the `ColonPanel` class.  The problem I am having is with the `DigitPanel` class.  I have the code written to only display one panel right now, but the digit panel wants to take up the entire JFrame when I run the program. Can someone please tell me what the problem is?

**Main class:**

```
public class DigitalTimeUI extends JFrame {

    public DigitalTimeUI() {
        JFrame clock = new JFrame("Clock");
        clock.setSize(605, 250);

        clock.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        clock.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        clock.setResizable(false);

        clock.add(new TitlePanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        clock.add(new DigitPane(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        clock.pack();
        clock.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class DigitPane extends JPanel {

        DigitPanel[] hourDigit = new DigitPanel[]{new DigitPanel(), new DigitPanel()};
        DigitPanel[] minDigit = new DigitPanel[]{new DigitPanel(), new DigitPanel()};
        DigitPanel[] secDigit = new DigitPanel[]{new DigitPanel(), new DigitPanel()};
        private String hour = pad(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR));
        private String min = pad(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        private String sec = pad(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND));
        private char[] hours = hour.toCharArray();
        private char[] minutes = min.toCharArray();
        private char[] seconds = sec.toCharArray();

        public DigitPane() {
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 72));
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

            JPanel digitsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            digitsPanel.setSize(new Dimension(605, 100));

            digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

            label.setText(String.valueOf(hours[0]));
            hourDigit[0].add(label);
            digitsPanel.add(hourDigit[0]);

            digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

            label.setText(String.valueOf(hours[1]));
            hourDigit[1].add(label);
            digitsPanel.add(hourDigit[1]);
            digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

            digitsPanel.add(new ColonPanel());
            digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

            label.setText(String.valueOf(minutes[0]));
            minDigit[0].add(label);
            digitsPanel.add(minDigit[0]);
            digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

            label.setText(String.valueOf(minutes[1]));
            minDigit[1].add(label);
            digitsPanel.add(minDigit[1]);
            digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

            digitsPanel.add(new ColonPanel());
            digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

            label.setText(String.valueOf(seconds[0]));
            secDigit[0].add(label);
            digitsPanel.add(secDigit[0]);
            digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

            label.setText(String.valueOf(seconds[1]));
            secDigit[0].add(label);
            digitsPanel.add(secDigit[1]);
            digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

            this.add(digitsPanel);
        }
    }

    protected String pad(int value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(value));
        while (sb.length() < 2) {
            sb.insert(0, "0");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DigitalTimeUI();
    }

    public class panelPadding extends JPanel {

        public panelPadding() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5, 80));
        }
    }
}
```

**TitlePanel:**

```
public class TitlePanel extends JPanel {

    JLabel title;

    public TitlePanel() {
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(605, 100));
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        title = new JLabel("DIGITAL CLOCK");
        title.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 72));
        title.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        this.add(title);
    }
}
```

**DigitPanel:**

```
public class DigitPanel extends JPanel {

    public DigitPanel() {
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

The title panel (for whatever reason) does not take up the whole frame when I resize it, but the digit panel does, and I have no idea why.  I tried the `.setLocation()`, `.setLayout()`, `.setSize()`, and a few other things and nothing seems to work.

The second question that perhaps could be answered here would be, what would be the best way to create each of the Digit Panels?  I was playing around with a while loop and a switch statement earlier, but didn't get anywhere because I kept running into the first problem I addressed.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that BorderLayout is the most appropriate for you to use. I suggest that you check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html for more information about all the layout managers in the standard API. If you insist on using BorderLayout, start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html. Pay special attention to how a BorderLayout divides up the window.

Comment: @Code-Guru Thanks for the link.  From that, it seems Grid or Gridbag would be best, yes?

Comment: @DarthCthulhu `GridLayout` will ensure that each element in the cell are the same size.  This may note suit your needs, as you may not want the colon components to be the same size.  If you do, then yes, it would work perfectly.

Comment: Note that you are not limited to using only one layout, or even one kind. You can nest them by using several JPanels. You can definitely do what you want with a GridbagLayout. You can also do it with nested BoxLayouts. I'm not sure which will take less work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BorderLayout` has 5 distinct areas that components can be added.  By default, if you do not specify a location, the components are added to the `CENTER` position.

In you code you are doing this...

```
clock.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
clock.add(new TitlePanel())
clock.add(new DigitPanel()).setLocation(5, 125);
```

This is basically replacing the `TitlePane` with the `DigitialPanel`, meaning the `TitlePane` will not show.

Also, using `setLocation` is not only pointless (as the value will be discard once the panel is revalidated) but is also discouraged.

I would;

1. Add the `TitlePanel` to the `NORTH` position (`clock.add(new TitlePane(), BorderLayout.NORTH))`)
2. Create ANOTHER `JPanel` (something like `digitsPanel`) and set to use a `GridLayout`, something like (`digitsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 8))`).
3. Add each `DigitalPane` to the `digitsPanel` (including the colons)
4. Add the `digitsPanel` to `CENTER` position of the `clock` - `clock.add(digitsPanel)`

The only problem with this, is each panel (on the `digitsPanel`) will be the same size.

If this doesn't meet your needs, I'd encourage you to using either `FlowLayout` or `GridBagLayout` if you need to more control over the layout

**Updated**

```
DigitPane[] hourDigit = new DigitPane[]{new DigitPane(), new DigitPane()};
DigitPane[] minDigit = new DigitPane[]{new DigitPane(), new DigitPane()};
DigitPane[] secDigit = new DigitPane[]{new DigitPane(), new DigitPane()};

JPanel digitsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
digitsPanel.add(hourDigit[0]);
digitsPanel.add(hourDigit[1]);
digitsPanel.add(new ColonPane());
digitsPanel.add(minDigit[0]);
digitsPanel.add(minDigit[1]);
digitsPanel.add(new ColonPane());
digitsPanel.add(secDigit[0]);
digitsPanel.add(secDigit[1]);
```

Comment: Okay so everything I seem to find on GridbagLayouts is using them within a single panel.  What I'm trying to do is just organize the panels as shown above in the frame, yet I can't seem to find anything that tells me how to do that with GridbagLayouts.

Comment: Really.  Did you try anything?  I've added a really simple example

Comment: Okay, I've updated the original question. I implemented what you added in the above update but the DigitPanels won't display at all. Any idea why?

Comment: You didn't add `digitsPanel` to anything

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb for missing that! haha. Almost done, but one more issue and I have no idea what's going on here... When I run the program, it is printing all of the numbers overlapping on the same panel. It makes all the black number panels and colon panels, it just doesn't put the numbers in the correct place.

Comment: You've tried adding a the same instance of a label to each of the digit panels.  A instance of a component can only be added to a single container.  In your `DigitPanel`, there should be a `JLabel`, to which you can apply a value of between 0-9

Comment: Thanks, you've been so much help for this.  I still haven't figured out what the problem is with my setDigit method though, so I'm just going to post another question on that.